# Search in multiple index , 'query_shard_exception' when fields are not present

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I'm trying to search in multiple indexes, but the fields and mapping for each index are different. Like one index is having nested path.

When I'm trying to query on index's I'm getting error for the index which are not having the nested path.

```
    {
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "term": {
            "a": "good"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "a.b": "sample"
          }
        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "x.y.z",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "should": [
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "x.y.z.id.keyword": "test@gamil.com"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

in above the nested path x.y.z is only present for one index.

I tried finding a solution, found `ignore_unavailable`. But it will ignore the index not having nested path, but I need the document's in that index which matches other condition in the query.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query by replacing `your-index` with the name of the index that contains the nested field.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "term": {
            "a": "good"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "a.b": "sample"
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "_index": "your-index"
                }
              },
              {
                "nested": {
                  "path": "x.y.z",
                  "query": {
                    "bool": {
                      "should": [
                        {
                          "term": {
                            "x.y.z.id.keyword": "test@gamil.com"
                          }
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: still getting 
`[nested] failed to find nested object under path`

Comment: Can you share your mapping?

Comment: `{
  nested: {
      path: "a/b/c",
      ignore_unmapped: true,
      query: { bool: { should: [] } }
  }
`

Was able to solve issue by adding `ignore_unmapped: true`